# How to separate docker and docker-compose from Django source folder

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to achieve this project layout structure:

```
project root:
    - docker:
        - docker-compose.yml
        - Dockerfile-app
        - Dockerfile-mysql
    - src:
        - djangoproj
            - core
            - requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-app
    command: /bin/bash -c "cd /var/www/app/src/djangoprj && pip install -r requirements-develop.tx  && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 || sleep 100000"
    container_name: website_app
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/app
    working_dir: /var/www/app/src/djangoproj

  mysql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-mysql
    container_name: website_mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: local
      MYSQL_USER: yoo
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
```

This basically works, the only issue I have, it is that the requirements are built every single time.

What I would like is that in the Dockerfile-app to copy the requirements.txt file and then run the pip install which I expect to run only when the requirements.txt was changed.

Inside Dockerfile-app:

```
ADD src/djangoproj/requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

From what I know in docker I can't access the parent folder.
I was also trying to do

```
app:
  build:
    context: ..
```

But doesn't output anything... so I don't know what it is going on...

When is the volume added to the docker container?

Any help will be so much appreciated

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be ADD ../src/djangoproj/requirements.txt /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with `context: ../`. Once the context is specified, you can access the requirements file in the same directory level.

Update the Dockerfile to to the following

```
ADD ./src/djangoproj/requirements.txt /
```

and the docker-compose.yml to point to the Dockerfile in the docker directory. This is required because the build context has now moved up to the parent directory.

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
```

My file layout looks like this:

```
$ tree .
.
├── docker
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── docker-compose.yml
└── src
    └── requirements.txt

2 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: Thx Shoan, I actually tried that, but when was starting to build there was no output so I was stopping it. It looks like it requires a lot of time to start building as it probably packs all the root directory, which is quite big. Do you recommend a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Were you not seeing any output after executing `docker-compose up` or was it just stuck at a step for a long time?

Comment: When I do `docker-compose build app` it shows `Building app` for more than 5 minutes and after that is starts showing the steps eg. `Step 1/7 : FROM python:latest`. I would like to reduce that waiting time and I am afraid that is due to the fact that the context is the root directory, which is full of things, like node modules and others stuff.